# How i can list all the numbers between the two given numbers without bulit-in functions

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function that makes the same job as `[a..b]` by using the `:` operator and guards.

is it possible to do it? where should I begin?

```
 list a b 
            | a < b = print[a..b]
            | otherwise = print[a,a-1..b]
```

Comment: You can use recursion. Note that, when `a<=b`, the list `[a..b]` is the same as `a : [a+1 .. b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deriving it from the laws it must follow, i.e.

```
list a b | a > b = []
list a b | a <= b = [a..b]
                  = a : [(a+1)..b]
```

But then we can read the last equation *right to left* to get

```
[(a+1)..b] = list (a+1) b
```

and substituting it back into the last law gives us the definition that we needed.

*update:* so looks like what you really wanted is to count up or down depending on the relation between `a` and `b`. This just needs some tweaking:

```
list a b | a == b = [a]
list a b | a < b  = [a..b]
                  = a : [(a+1)..b]
                  = a : list (a+1) b
list a b | a > b  = [a,a-1..b]
                  = a : [a-1,a-2..b]
                  = a : list (a-1) b
```

This will perform some redundant checks while counting. These can be avoided by defining two specialized internal functions for the counting up or down, and using those after the initial checks.

Comment: ok. what about if a is greater than b. in this situation can we get an output like [9,8,7,6]

Comment: @mert you can't do it in the same function. the solution then is to have one top-level function which compares a and b and decides which of the two possible internal functions to call -- one which is counting up, or the other which is counting down. and you said "same job as `[a..b]`" but `[a..b] == [], when a > b`.

Comment: `(...) = list` is a valid operator name so `1...4 = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @mert actually it is possible. just need to change the `<=` in guard to `<` and add the third clause, with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it better to compare with the parent function or within the same function? @Will Ness

```
list a b| a < b = greaterB a b    
list a b| a >= b = greaterA a b


greaterB a b 
           | a > b = []             
           | a <= b = a:greaterB(a+1) b

greaterA a b 
           | a >= b = a:greaterA(a-1) b               
           | a < b = []
```

Comment: this kind of notifications does not work; I only just saw your answer. will read it now.  .... certainly it isn't advisable to have the two of them defined globally. this is known as "polluting the global namespace". :) .... good naming is important; I'd much rather prefer "ascending" and "descending" instead. so, put them inside as internal definitions. there also might be a slight performance advantage compared with just one function. (this is known as worker/wrapper; look it up:) )